# Android - How to open browser in private/incognito mode?

Tags: android, browser, incognito-mode

I need to open an url in incognito mode. How can I do that? Is it even possible?

Comment: see this link if it helps https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#incognito

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it on android.